# Why must the inverse function be of this form?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I am reading a proof about the implicit function theorem that uses the inverse function theorem. There they make a statement that I do not understand.

The inverse function theorem statement is:

> Assume that U is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ and let $f:U
> \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with continuous partial
> derivatives. Assume that
> $(\bar{x},\bar{y})=(\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2,\ldots,\bar{x}_m,y)$ is a
> point in U such that $f(\bar{x},\bar{y})=0.$ Assume also that
> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\bar{x},\bar{y})\ne 0$. Then there exists
> an open set $U_0$ about $\bar{x}$ and a differentiable function $g:
>  U_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(\bar{x})=\bar{y}$ and
> $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x \in U_0$. The derivative of $g$ is given by
> $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  x_i}(\bar{x},\bar{y})}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  y}(\bar{x},\bar{y})}$.

In the proof they define the function $F: \mathbb{R}^{m+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ given by $F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,y)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,y))$.

They calculate the Jacobian of $F$ and show that the determinant in $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ is nonzero. And then they can use the inverse function theorem.

Then they make the statement: **It is easy to see that the inverse function of $F$ must be of the form**
$G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,z)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,h(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,z))$, where $h$ is a differentiable funciton.

But why is this easy to see? How do we know that the function must be of this form?

Comment: Does your question boil down to this: "As $F$ preserves the first $m$ co-ordinates, why does $G$ preserve the first $m$ co-ordinates?" Or is there more to it?

Comment: @Stinking Bishop I think it boils down to that yes.

Comment: Well, if $G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,z)=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m,w)$ then $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,z)=F(G(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,z)))$ ($F$ and $G$ are inverses of each other) $=F(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m,w)=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m,t)$ for some $t$ (note $F$ preserves the first $m$ co-ordinates) - i.e. $x_1=y_1,x_2=y_2,\ldots,x_m=y_m$.

Comment: Now you can always call the *last* co-ordinate of $G$ a "real function $h$" - but $G$ being differentiable implies that $h$ is differentiable, as $h=\pi_{m+1}\circ G$, where $\pi_{m+1}$ is the *projection* to the $m+1$st co-ordinate.

Comment: Thank you very much.